# How to get facebook friends list using FBSDKGraphRequest

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting total count in the response, but the data is empty. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a list of the user's friends after requesting the `user_friends` permission and running the below code, this will return the `uid` of each friend.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{user-id}/friends"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

To fetch friends on a specific friends list you will need to request the permission `read_custom_friendlists` and run the below code with the friendw list id returned from the `/{user-id}/friendlists` edge

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{friend-list-id}"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I have a doubt. Should i pass /{user-id}/friends or /{123456789}/friends.

Comment: `{user-id}` is a placeholder, you should use `/123456789/friends`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not getting data. The response is                                                                                                                                                             data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 796;
    };

Comment: @NatarajanChandrasekharan Have you requested the permissions above?

Comment: I am not getting data. But i am getting total count. How to get the data. Can anyone help with this.

Comment: @NatarajanChandrasekharan As per my above comment, you need to request the permissions to retrieve data. Have you done this? As soon as you request and allow permission `user_friends`, data will be returned.

Comment: Can you please comment me the code to request for permission